# Unclear on how to secure endpoints with MERN stack REST API

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, rest

This is a pretty general problem, but I'm building a website that is meant to load, update, and store data related to student grades, and allow only my application to do any of this modification. There is no login system, but there are post requests, get requests, etc. for different tables. I want only my application to be able to access the endpoints and make modifications.

I saw many systems that use a token system, but all that I could find used a login system, which, because there are no users, I was unsure on how to implement.

Comment: What does *my application* mean in this context. Anyone who goes to your website should be able to call the API from/using your site?

Comment: AFAIK there is no real good way to restrict access to only that particular client if the client is public. The client needs to tell your server who it is in some way, and if anyone can access it that information inherently needs to be embedded in the client. You can probably keep away most unwanted traffic with simple CORS checks and similar, but there is no real security in it.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.